# How do I make comments in OpenCart Checkout Required?

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to make the comments section on the opencart checkout process required.

Everything that I tried either breaks the checkout or the mod doesn't work. I'm running OpenCart version 1.5.6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the comment field shows up in both the payment method and the shipping method section, you need to validate it in both.  As there are already `validate()` methods in both controllers all you need to do is check that the field is not empty and return a warning if it is.

The two files are:

```
catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_method.php
catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method.php
```

Look toward the end of both files and find the very last occurence of `if (!$json) {` which is basically the green light to move forward.  Immediately before it you can add you validation code.  I'd use something like this:

```
if (!trim($this->request->post['comment'])) {
    $json['error']['warning'] = 'Comment is required';
}
```

You may also want to consider modifying the respective tpl files (`catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl` and `catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_method.tpl`) to indicate to your customer that the field is required.  You could change:

```
<b><?php echo $text_comments; ?></b>
```

into...

```
<b><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $text_comments; ?></b>
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding what I need. I will give this a try and update you. Appears that some people are a little quick to edit people posts for some reason. Seems like every time I post something on here someone has to edit it. If I didnt think it belonged in my post I wouldn't put it there. Sorry for the rant. Just get old when you re read you post 1000 times before posting and they still heavily edit it.

Comment: I lookde at the edits that were made and OpenCart should not have been removed from the title.  It makes no sense now... not sure why they would do that but I'll flag it.  Remember to accept my answer if it works for you - which it will.

Comment: I use "One Page Checkout" and that code you gave me broke everything after where the text box appears. I prolly should have mentioned that but I didn't think it would matter.

Comment: Yes you should have mentioned that.  There are at least a dozen "One Page Checkout" extensions and all of them completely replace the OpenCart checkout process.  As it is, your question is impossible to answer as it related to proprietary software of which the codebase can not be publicly disclosed.

Comment: And you should still accept my answer as correct it does answer your question.  If you had mentioned One Page Checkout your question would probably be flagged and removed. You should just contact the developer for support.

Comment: That's the problem. The developer has been missing for years.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend contacting commercial support http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=partner/partner.  You can find me in there as well as many other qualified developers.  Something like this should be quick and inexpensive.